# Linksys WRT160N with DD-WRT as a second access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a [Linksys WRT160N](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-product?pid=01t80000003K7b9AAC) running [DD-WRT](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) in another room of my house, connected to the main router through a 30 meter cable. The main router is the one that has a internet connection and it provides Internet to the Linksys-WRT160N.

The Linksys provides me Internet access the way is installed today, but I need to change networks every time I want to connect back and forth.

I want the Linksys to provide signal from the main router and transmit the same network ID. I don't want to change it manually on my PC every time I want Internet access from the Linksys.

How would I do that?

Comment: These three links https://forum.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge , https://forum.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Routers , and https://forum.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses common private IP addresses as examples, and makes a couple assumptions as to what you want. (adjust these to meet your network settings if you need to)

Router 1 (IP 192.168.1.1) (Subnet Mask "/24" or 255.255.255.0)

- (WAN-Port going to ISP modem,ONT,Etc)
- (LAN-port going to router-2 LAN-Port)
- (Wireless Channel = 11)
- (Wireless SSID = MyHomeNetwork
- (WPA2 Pre-shared key = (Use 16 digit alpha-numerical with upper lower and special characters)
- (DHCP enabled 192.168.1.50 ~ 192.168.1.200)

---

DD-WRT Setup

In the Web user interface, Under the setup tab --> Basic Setup sub-tab.
[image: wan setup]
You can disable Spanning Tree Protocol to recover a minimal amount of ram if you wish.
(It stops [broadcast storms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_radiation) and [switching loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_loop))
Go down to the bottom of the page and save. don't apply just yet.

---

- Set the local LAN Address to the last in the subnet ".254" (save
  don't apply)
- Set the WAN port assigned to switch option. (why not? its an extra
  port.)
- Set the DHCP option to forwarder to ensure clients of this AP get a
  IP address from the first router. (Save, don't apply)
- Set the NTP settings to match your local time zone, and input a server IP or DNS name to grab some time updates . (We will be using this later. Save, don't apply.)
  [image: network setup]

Head on over to the Wireless tab --> Basic settings.

- Set the SSID exactly the same as the first routers SSID.
- Set the network mode to n-only if you don't need 802.11g backwards compatibility.
- Make sure to set the channel so it doesn't conflict with the first.
- Save, don't apply.
  [image: wireless-basic]

---

Head over to the Wireless Security sub-tab

- Security Mode = WPA2 Personal
- WPA Algorithms = AES (!allowing TKIP will degrade data rates to 54Mbps!)
- WPA Shared Key = Exact same key used on router-1.
- Save Dont apply.

  ---

  Go to the Security tab --> Firewall sub-tab
- Disable the Firewall
- Save, don't apply.
  [image: Firewall]

  ---

  Go to the Administration tab --> keep-alive sub-tab.
  Set the router to reboot at a convenient time so you are not disrupting users. 
  [image: keep-alive]
  Save, Reboot, and Enjoy.